# Unable to configure rest in spring (no springboot, please)

Tags: spring, rest

I'm struggling to configure rest in spring. Springboot magic configuration works, but I'm not asking about that. I thought I have to add:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

anotate configuration with @EnableWebMvc and done. In most 'tutorials' it's like that. But that does not work. It fails on missing javax.servlet.ServletContext. I add it (no tutorial does that), and it fails on "no servlet context set".

What is wrong here? App even fails to boot.

maven:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.14.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>



      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>${finalName}-notShaded</finalName>
        </configuration>

      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>${finalName}</finalName>
              <transformers>
                <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
```

main:

```
try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()) {
            SimpleCommandLinePropertySource sclps = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
            ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(sclps);
            ctx.register(Configuration.class);
            ctx.refresh();
            ctx.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SdpException("Error initializing spring", e);
        }
```

configuration:

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"..."})
@EnableWebMvc
public class Configuration {
}
```

Comment: Why a main? FIrst, if it's a webapp you'll need a web.xml or a class which implements `WebApplicationInitializer`

Comment: a) I came to spring from EE specification world, I migth be doing something (and most probably are) wrong.  
    
b) I want to self contained app. Which fires app server and runs. I don't want to build ear/war and deploy it to running app server. Thus the need for main method. Is that correct?    
c) I tried to have my @Configuration class  implement WebApplicationInitializer, but what to put in it? I understand what is ServletContext, but what shall I configure there?? I will gladly wrote even web.xml, but what configuration shall be in it? Nowadays it can be missing altogether.

Comment: btw. —  how do you do linebreaks here?? From documentation "learn more about formatting": `End a line with two spaces to add a <br/> linebreak:` it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a Spring webapp in a self-contained app manually, you can:

- Use an embedded container (Tomcat, Jetty) and initialize it manually (in your `main` method. This will allow you to have your webapp executable as a jar).
- Create a class that implements `WebApplicationInitializer` which will be responsible to create and initialize the Spring context

In your custom `WebApplicationinitializer` class, you juste have to tell explicitely what are your configuration classes or scan a package you choose to find all `@Configuration` classes.

I made a POC on [Github](https://github.com/gWombat/springembeddedtomcat) based on this very good [article](https://auth0.com/blog/spring-5-embedded-tomcat-8-gradle-tutorial/). I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help!